GNU make: avoid rules to be executed when files exist already
I have the following make file snippet:
DATA_DIR ?= cpp/gen_data_cpp/build
TXT_FILES := $(wildcard ${DATA_DIR}/*.txt)
BIFI_FILES := $(TXT_FILES:.txt=.txtbifikreversed)
${BIFI_FILES}: ${TXT_FILES} cpp/build/exe_convert_multicov2rivet
    bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3   
bifi: $(BIFI_FILES)   
line: cpp/build/exe_project_bifi_along_path  $(BIFI_FILES)
    bash script.sh file1 file2

each time I call make line, the rule bifi will be triggered which is time expensive, in fact, the rule bifi will produce all files defined in ${BIFI_FILES}.  So they only need to be done once, could someone explain to me what I did wrong here?

In the above makefile the target bifi doesn't have a recipe, so make won't run anything for that target and it can't possibly be "time expensive".  Please be more clear about exactly what happens and how you WANT it to work.  Maybe edit your question and add in a (shortened) example of the results you get when you run make and show what parts are wrong.  The most important thing for using make is to be clear in your mind, for each invocation of a recipe what inputs does it take, and what outputs does it generate.  If you can define that clearly for us we can help.

make bifi will execute bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3

Are you sure your bash scripts are creating/updating the files you think they are?

Yes, make bifi will run that command but only because the target bifi depends on the $(BIFI_FILES).  It's the recipe for that rule which actually runs things, not the rule for bifi.

First, lets do some formatting for easier viewing:
DATA_DIR ?= cpp/gen_data_cpp/build
TXT_FILES := $(wildcard ${DATA_DIR}/*.txt)
BIFI_FILES := $(TXT_FILES:.txt=.txtbifikreversed)

${BIFI_FILES}: ${TXT_FILES} cpp/build/exe_convert_multicov2rivet
    bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3   

bifi: $(BIFI_FILES)   

line: cpp/build/exe_project_bifi_along_path  $(BIFI_FILES)
    bash script.sh file1 file2

The target bifi does not have recipe so by itself it does not do anything. But it has prerequisite $(BIFI_FILES) and that executes $(BIFI_FILES) target.
The target $(BIFI_FILES) is a target with many files. Assuming you have a.txt and b.txt in your ${DATA_DIR}, then $(BIFI_FILES) target would become:
datadir/a.txtbifikreversed datadir/b.txtbifikreversed: datadir/a.txt datadir/b.txt cpp/build/exe_convert_multicov2rivet
    bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3   

So it will check the timestamp on all three source files (a.txt, b.txt, and exe_convert_multicov2rivet) and if any of them are newer than most recent target (a.txtbifikreversed or b.txtbifikreversed) the bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3 will be executed.
Assuming cpp/build/exe_convert_multicov2rivet is a convertor of all *.txt into *.txtbifikreversed - that will run for all files, regardless of do they need update or not.
What you should have instead is a convertor of one .txt into one .txtbifikreversed:
${DATA_DIR}/%.txtbifikreversed : ${DATA_DIR}/%.txt $(process_one_file)
     bash $(process_one_file) $<

And now, if any of *.txtbifikreversed is needed to be updated for line (or bifi) target, and this is already done by including $(BIFI_FILES) as prerequisite for line - the rule just for one .txt will start.
Updating convert ($(process_one_file)) will of course force all .txt files to be processed.

"A target with many files" is an unfortunate way to describe it.  What the OP actually has is many separate targets, all having a rule in common.  In addition to that being more formally correct, I find that it makes make's behavior in this area easier to understand.

"So it will check the timestamp on all three source files (a.txt, b.txt, and exe_convert_multicov2rivet) and if any of them are newer than most recent target (a.txtbifikreversed or b.txtbifikreversed) the bash $(S_process_pt_cloud) $< 3 will be executed." that is not true and not how it works.  This is why we need to understand exactly what the inputs and outputs of each recipe (command) are, so we can get the right set of rules in make to match that behavior.
